# Modelica annotation derivative: noDerivative versus zeroDerivative

Tags: annotations, modelica, derivative

I have successfully used `annotation(derivative)` in Modelica functions. Now I have reached a point where I think I need to use `zeroDerivative` or `noDerivative`, but from the specification I just do not understand what is the difference, and when to use what.
https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch12.html#declaring-derivatives-of-functions
It seems `zeroDerivative` is for time-constant parameters??
Does somebody have a simple example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use zeroDerivative to refer to inputs that are non-varying, i.e. parameters or constant values.

Use noDerivative for signals that do not have a derivative value.  For example if an input signal comes from an external function.

Answer (score 4):

The important case for `noDerivative` is when the input is "redundant".

As an example consider the computation of density for some media in MSL:

The density computation is found in Modelica.Media.R134a.R134a_ph.density_ph (note this does not contain any derivative in itself):

```
algorithm
   d := rho_props_ph(
        p,
        h,
        derivsOf_ph(
          p,
          h,
          getPhase_ph(p, h)));
```

where the top function called is:

```
function rho_props_ph
  "Density as function of pressure and specific enthalpy"
  extends Modelica.Icons.Function;

  input SI.Pressure p "Pressure";
  input SI.SpecificEnthalpy h "Specific enthalpy";
  input Common.InverseDerivatives_rhoT derivs
    "Record for the calculation of rho_ph_der";
  output SI.Density d "Density";
algorithm 
  d := derivs.rho;
  annotation (
    derivative(noDerivative=derivs) = rho_ph_der ...);
end rho_props_ph;
```

So the `derivs`-argument is sort of redundant and is given by `p` and `h`; and we don't need to differentiate it again. If you send in a `derivs`-argument that isn't given in this way may give unpredictable result, but describing this in detail would be too complicated. (There was some idea of `noDerivative=something` - but even just specifying it turned out to be too complicated.)

For `zeroDerivative` the corresponding requirement is that the arguments have zero derivative; that is straightforward to verify and if non-zero we cannot use the specific derivative (it is possible to specify multiple derivatives and use another derivative one for that case).